# Octave: Getting value with full precision through csvread()

Tags: matlab, octave

When i read a csv file using csvread(), the values have only 4 point precision, eg. -5.2556 instead of the actual value -5.2555569189. How can i get the full value?

```
>> a(1,7)
ans = -5.2556
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Octave [only displays 5 significant digits](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Terminal-Output.html)

> By default, Octave displays 5 significant digits in a human readable form (option ‘short’ paired with ‘loose’ format for matrices). If `format` is invoked without any options, this default format is restored.

If you want to change this, use `format` with an input argument to allow you to see more digits in the command window display.

```
format long g
```