# Octave: How to read formated input from file

Tags: file, io, octave

I need to read all 15 decimal-digit number from a txt file and store them into an array. I cannot find an example of how to invoke format like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550006/octave-getting-value-with-full-precision-through-csvread) great answer so I after a lot of effort for something like that, I thought its the perfect time to ask. Any help?

```
fileID = fopen('data.txt','r')
formatSpec = format long G 
A = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec)
fclose('data.txt')
```

and the numbers are like :

```
 4.92999929999999972
 5.92456845523467798 
 8.93491235999999996
```

Comment: `formatSpec` is not a valid format spec for `fscanf`. Please read the function’s documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#bt_j35z-1-formatSpec

Answer (score 2):

If I paste your numbers into a file called `data.txt` and then run

```
x = load("data.txt");
format long
x
```

it prints out:

```
x =

    4.929999300000000
    5.924568455234678
    8.934912360000000
```

These have been rounded to 16 significant figures because that is the maximum precision in which Octave stores data. Your numbers have 18 sig figs but I am not aware of any way of storing those. If you need higher precision then I don't think it's available in Octave, though it looks like it is on the developers' wish list, see: https://wiki.octave.org/Projects#High_Precision_Arithmetic_Computation.

Edit posted in response to comment below.

I don't think there is any way of using higher precision numbers in Octave. 64 bits is the word length of the processor so higher precision arithmetic has to be implemented in software and nobody has done that yet for Octave. According to the Octave manual the default format in which numbers are stored is IEEE 754 double precision (binary64) floating-point format (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). This uses 64 bits of which one is used for the sign, eleven for the exponent and 52 for the fractional part (i.e. the actual number itself). In decimal, 2^52 = 4503599627370496 which is 16 digits long, so 64 bits gives you 15 or 16 decimal sig.figs depending on the value of the fractional part of the number. There is a toolbox available for Matlab (https://www.advanpix.com/) that claims to enable arbitrary precision floating point numbers but both Matlab and the toolbox are commercial and very expensive. The Python numpy package has some higher precision data types. I haven't tried these but from what I have read they don't work very well.

If you just want to print out your numbers you could import them as a cell array of strings as follows:

```
filename = "data.txt";
fid = fopen (filename, "r");
x = textscan (fid, "%s");
fclose (fid);
```

then typing `x` at the terminal prints out:

```
x =
{
[1,1] =
{
    [1,1] = 4.92999929999999972
    [2,1] = 5.92456845523467798
    [3,1] = 8.93491235999999996
}

}
```

but these are strings and you can't do calculations with them. You can convert them to numbers using the function `str2double()` but then they will be truncated to 16 sig. figs. and you are back to where you started.

Actually, 16 sig. figs. should be plenty for most purposes. For comparison, the diameter of a hydrogen atom is approximately 1 Angstrom unit = 10^(-10)m, and 1000km is equal to 10^6m, so there are 10^16 Angstroms in 1000km, so 16 significant figures is enough to locate a hydrogen atom in 1000km. Higher precision is only needed for solving problems that suffer from the 'butterfly effect' where arbitrarily small quantities can 'blow up'.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer since it does not only it enabled me to store more than 2-3 sig figs , but it also informed be about this 16 sig fig Octave's limit. Do you know any way I can avoid this rounding ? I think I can go along missing two sig fig in the end of each number, but the rounding is a much bigger problem to me.Again, thank you for your answer.